# Can't npm install 'gulp-imagemin'

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-imagemin

On a fresh debian jessie ec2 instance I do the following:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install curl -y
- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
- mkdir /tmp/real_node_modules
- ln -s /tmp/real_node_modules node_modules
- npm install 'gulp-imagemin'

I then get this error:

```
> optipng-bin@3.1.2 postinstall /home/admin/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bin-build'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/real_node_modules/optipng-bin/lib/install.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
npm WARN install:optipng-bin@3.1.2 optipng-bin@3.1.2 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm WARN install:optipng-bin@3.1.2 Exit status 1

> jpegtran-bin@3.0.6 postinstall /home/admin/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'bin-build'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/real_node_modules/jpegtran-bin/lib/install.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
npm WARN install:jpegtran-bin@3.0.6 jpegtran-bin@3.0.6 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm WARN install:jpegtran-bin@3.0.6 Exit status 1
```

It goes without saying that things work without the symlinked node modules folder, however what I'm trying to figure out is why they don't work if you have a symlinked node modules folder.

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried running it in a directory which doesn't have a symlinked node_modules directory in it?

Comment: It goes without saying that this works if you don't have a symlinked node_modules directory. However I need to have one for my use case.

Comment: You should have made it clear in your question then. Trust me, nothing goes without saying on this site.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in npm version  3.9.3.

The fix is changing "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -" to "curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -"

EDIT: I'm learning now that npm 2.15.5 has similar issues unfortunately.